# Java 8 stream groupBy pojo

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a collection of pojos:

```
public class Foo {
    String name;
    String date;
    int count;
}
```

I need to iterate over collection, groupBy Foos by name and sum counts, then create new collection with pojos with summed count.

Here is how I do it now:

```
    List<Foo> foosToSum = ...

    Map<String, List<Foo>> foosGroupedByName = foosToSum.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getName));

    List<Foo> groupedFoos = foosGroupedByName.keySet().stream().map(name -> {
        int totalCount = 0;
        String date = "";
        for(Foo foo: foosGroupedByName.get(name)) {
            totalCount += foo.getCount();
            date = foo.getDate() //last is used
        }
        return new Foo(name, date, totalCount);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a more beauty way to do it with streams?

**UPDATE** Thanks everyone for help. All answers were great. 
I decided to create merge function in pojo.

The final solution looks like:

```
Collection<Foo> groupedFoos = foosToSum.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getName, Function.identity(), Foo::merge))
                    .values();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it either using `groupingBy` or using `toMap` collector, as for which to use is debatable so I'll let you decide on the one you prefer.

For better readability, I'd create a merge function in `Foo` and hide all the merging logic inside there.

This also means better maintainability as the more complex the merging gets, you only have to change *one place* and that is the `merge` method, not the stream query.

e.g.

```
public Foo merge(Foo another){
     this.count += another.getCount();
     /* further merging if needed...*/
     return this;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Collection<Foo> resultSet = foosToSum.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getName,
                    Function.identity(), Foo::merge)).values();
```

Note, the above merge function mutates the objects in the source collection, if instead, you want to keep it immutable then you can construct new `Foo`'s like this:

```
public Foo merge(Foo another){
      return new Foo(this.getName(), null, this.getCount() + another.getCount());
}
```

Further, if for some reason you *explicitly* require a `List<Foo>` instead of `Collection<Foo>` then it can be done by using the `ArrayList` copy constructor.

```
List<Foo> resultList = new ArrayList<>(resultSet);
```

**Update**

As @Federico has mentioned in the comments the last merge function above is expensive as it creates unnecessary objects that could be avoided. So, as he has suggested, a more friendly alternative is to proceed with the first merge function I've shown above and then change your stream query to this:

```
Collection<Foo> resultSet = foosToSum.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getName,
                        f -> new Foo(f.getName(), null, f.getCount()), Foo::merge))
                .values();
```

Comment: Hi Aominè! Just a comment... If you use `Function.identity()` as the value mapper function, it is correct that the elements of the source collection are mutated. So you propose to create new `Foo` elements when merging. While this works and is correct, it creates unnecessary objects. You could create a copy in the value mapper function (just use a copy constructor), and then merge over this copy, as in your original `merge` method.

Comment: Hi, @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I've seen your comment earlier but wasn't in a position to reply back. now I am :) . anyhow, you're correct and I have updated my answer accordingly. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hey Aominè great you've updated your already accepted answer ;) I had already upvoted in advance :)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner in fact, looking at my code again, it only created new objects when there is a key collision and in the case, there is no collision it would still maintain that particular object from the source. so you didn't only improve my code but solved a subtle issue :).

Comment: Aominè, yes, you are correct in that as well. I hadn't noticed it. Good, then. We killed two birds with one stone...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner , why it's necessary to create new objects, if we can mutate and reuse old. So the merge function will look like the original one, and `Function.identity()` remains.

Comment: @KirillBazarov if it's fine to mutate existing objects then you need not create new objects. I only suggested creating new objects if you didn't want to mutate existing objects.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thanks.

Comment: There is no any parallel execution and collection is in local scope in my case, so I believe it's safe to reuse same objects.

Comment: I don't get the point how your second(updated) version is better than the first. I feel only in the second one, you would create one `Foo` object each time (`valueMapper` in `toMap`) - while in the first one you use `Function.identity` and do a merge *only* when a key clashed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user7 The point is that merge function is better in updated version. But what to use, `Function.identity` or new Object is up to you, depending if you need new objects or modify existing. First merge function will create unnecessary objects if, for example there are more then 1 clash for same key.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could use a downstream collector in your `groupingBy` to immediately sum the counts. Afterwards, stream the map and map to Foos.

```
foosToSum.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getName,
                                        Collectors.summingInt(Foo::getCount)))
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .map(entry -> new Foo(entry.getKey(), null, entry.getValue()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

A more efficient solution could avoid grouping into a map only to stream it immediately, but sacrifices some readability (in my opinion):

```
foosToSum.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getName,
                                        Collectors.reducing(new Foo(),
                                                            (foo1, foo2) -> new Foo(foo1.getName(), null, foo1.getCount() + foo2.getCount()))))
         .values();
```

By reducing Foos instead of ints, we keep the name in mind and can immediately sum into Foo.

Comment: Great solution. But, I need to get latest date field from grouped by name Foos somehow. My mistake, I've written that is not important, but it is.

Comment: Well, you could try to just use `foo2.getDate()` instead of `null`. But then you rely on the foos still being ordered. If you wanna make sure, you can use something like `getLater(foo1.getDate(), foo2.getDate())`. As Aominè said in another answer, you could put all that logic in the Foo class and write `...reducing(new Foo(), Foo::merge)`